# Is there a maximum number of feature classes for an Esri File GeoDatabase?

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, error-000210

Is there a maximum number of feature classes for an Esri File GeoDatabase ? I'm running a script that creates feature classes, however, after around 1000 I receive a schema lock error:

```
ERROR 000210: Cannot create output.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [ArcGIS documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018s00000002000000), file geodatabase size and name limits are as follows:

> File geodatabase size: No limit
>
> Table or feature class size: 1 TB (default), 4 GB or 256 TB with
>   keyword
>
> **Number of feature classes and tables: 2,147,483,647**
>
> Number of fields in a feature class or table: 65,534
>
> Number of rows in a feature class or table: 2,147,483,647
>
> Geodatabase name length: Number of characters the operating system
>   allows in a folder name
>
> Feature class or table name length: 160 characters
>
> Field name length: 64 characters
>
> Text field width: 2,147,483,647

You're some way from the limit yet. Could you show us the script? Something else must be going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

1000 feature classes means several thousand files in one directory, which will mean sluggish response to any "list all files" request on any operating system.  This could certainly slow down lock creation and deletion, which would generate the error you're seeing.  Most of the theoretical FGDB maximums are not obtainable in the real world without significant delay.

You'd need to provide more information about *why* you need to create thousands of tables in one FGDB before a real solution to this issue could be offered.